# why Excel session has to be killed from Windows Task Manager on VBA error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel book with VBA. When an error is triggered, I try to close the entire Excel app. But I find the Excel session is still running in Windows Task Manager. So I have to kill the session before I can properly reboot the app and run the VBA program.

How can I handle errors so that even when there is an error I still can run the VBA program without killing and rebooting Excel itself?

Comment: show us your code please

Comment: This can happen if you open a workbook which is hidden or something.

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your sub/function write

```
'ErrHandler is a label we put at the bottom of our code section.
On Error Goto ErrHandler
```

and at the bottom of the function/sub

```
Exit Function

ErrHandler:

'Do something here if there is an error

'For Example
Msgbox(Err.Description)

End Function
```

or

```
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:

'Do something here if there is an error

'For Example
Msgbox(Err.Description)

End Sub
```

Note that you have to put the Exit statement or you will enter the code block at the end of the execution

The err object is used to get information about the error in the error section of the sub/function. You can use this to do different things based on the type of error.

eg.

```
Select Case err.Number

Case 13
    Msgbox("Type Mismatch, macro will continue")

    'Go back to the point of the error and resume code execution..
    Resume Next

Case Else

    Msgbox("A fatal error has occurred. Macro will end " & err.Description)

End Select
```

Nice reference for catching specific error codes.

http://www.mcoffice.com/faq/edi/errors.html

Answer (score 1):

if you have given the user control over the application with the following lines

```
xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.UserControl = True
```

it will not go away, else `End`ing the sub or function should release the errant process